# How to compute the recursive sequence with square?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider a sequence defined by
$x_{n+1}^2=ax_n^2+bx_n+c$,where $a,b,c>0$ and $x_n >0$,
is there any general method to compute the exact form of $x_n$?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean $ax_n^2+bx_n+c$ ?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @TheSilverDoe This is not a quadratic map, since $x_{n+1}$ is squared.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't define a sequence because $x_{n+1}$ could be

$+\sqrt{a x_n^2+b x_n+c}$

or

$-\sqrt{a x_n^2+b x_n+c}$.

Let's say you set $a=b=c=1$ and $x_0 = 1$, then the relation says

$x_1^2 = 1\cdot 1^2 + 1\cdot 1+ 1 = 3$.

This doesn't define $x_1$, it could be that $x_1 = \sqrt{3}$ or $x_1 = -\sqrt{3}$.

Do you have any information about the sign of $x_n$?

Comment: Oh yeah, all $x_n$ and a, b, c are positive

Comment: In that case you may write the recursion as $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{a x_n^2 + b x_n +c}$ and the sequence will be some [nested radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical) which, except for some very special cases, cannot be simplified.

Answer (score -3):

If you know $x_{n+1}$ then you can use the quadratic formula to find $x_n$.

Comment: There is not much difference. The left side is a quadratic in $x_{n+1}$ and the right side is a quadratic in $x_n$. The quadratic formula gives two solutions in general.

Comment: @Somos I agree, but the OP was asking about how to solve for $x_n$ so that’s what I addressed.

Comment: I wonder why my answer was downvoted.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question. What is wanted is a formula for $x_n$ involving $n$ and  $x_0$.

Comment: @Somos oh- the wording of the question is confusing.